How to cython with source programs in memory?
dear all:
I am generating customized pyd with cython in a server.
I want to protect my source code of the pyd.
Thus I would prefer to encrypt the source code and then when I need generate the customized pyd, I can decrypt it and use cython to generate the customized pyd.
The procedure works only when cython accept source code in memory.
But I could not find information, documentation, and tutorials in this regard.
Is this possible at all?
Is there an API of cython that I can call to start cython to read source code in memory?
I think this capability will greatly enhance source code protection.
Or can someone tell me how to modify cython source code to make such an API?
Then I can use this cython version for my purpose.
Thanks

This feels like it would actually be easier to de-obfuscate this scheme than if you just distributed the compiled pyd files. Because 1) your whole source is a string in memory, 2) Cython goes through intermediate c files which contain relatively readable code

The closest Cython has is cython.inline. That has fairly significant limitations though and does a lot of caching which will likely make it trivial to find the source code.
